# PHP- Regular expression - how to read from Right to left

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have below example

```
$game = "hello999hello888hello777last";
preg_match('/hello(.*?)last/', $game, $match);
```

The above code returns **999hello888hello777**, what I need is to retrieve the value just before **Last**, i.e **777**. So I need to read regular expression to read from right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the last set of digits before the string `last`

```
$game = "hello999hello888hello777last";
preg_match('/hello(\d+)last$/', $game, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Output Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello777last
    [1] => 777
)
```

So you would need `$match[1];` for the 777 value

Comment: can you explain this please

Comment: @KirubaPaul Sure the `$` is an anchor saying that matches start at the at the end of the string, the `\d+` matches one or more digits between the strings `hello` and `last`. Hope I explained this correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
$game = strrev($game);
```

How about that? :D

Then just reverse the regular expression ^__^

Answer (score 2):

Why not just reverse the string? Use PHP's [strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) and then just reverse your regular expression.

```
$game = "hello999hello888hello777last";
preg_match('/tsal(.*?)elloh/', strrev($game), $match);
```

Comment: You will need to adjust the regular expression then too, i.e., search for "olleh" rather than "hello".

Comment: this is just example , but mine real time example is complex like 
preg_match_all('/<a href=\'search.php\?q(.*?)Next/', strrev($content), $conten);

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that although `.*` matches reluctantly, i. e. as few characters as possible, it still starts matching right after `hello`, and since it matches *any* characters, it will match right across "boundaries" (`last` and `hello` in your case).

Therefore you need to be more explicit about the fact that it's not legal to match across boundaries, and that's what lookahead assertions are for:

```
preg_match('/hello((?:(?!hello|last).)*)last(?!.*(?:hello|last)/', $game, $match);
```

Now the match between `hello` and `last` is prohibited from containing `hello` and/or `last`, and it's not allowed to have `hello` or `last` after the match.